# Is Deleuze's characterization of Sartre (that his central obsession was "lakes of non-being and the viscosity of matter") fair?

Tags: ontology, sartre

In his essay entitled *My teacher* Gilles Deleuze characterises the "central obsession" of Sartre as being "lakes of non-being and the viscosity of matter".

Is this a fair characterisation of Sartre's work ?

Comment: Without being familiar with Sartres work, but after trying to read nausea, I think I would.

Comment: for what reason?

Comment: Wouldn't you feel nauseaus if surrounded by 'lakes of non-being and the vicosity of matter'. The viscosity of matter refers to his human beings too. One doesn't get the feeling of warmth from his book Nausea. Perhaps he's describing it as it is. Perhaps he's describing it through his central obsession.

Comment: i think Sartre would say people are surrounded by objects and events that possess being to a greater extent than the foundation of subjectivity, it is people for Sartre who are the lakes of non being, being influenced by Heidegger Sartre finds the being of objects as something that in a way resists itself - (wikipedia definition "Viscosity is a measure of the resistance of a fluid which is being deformed by either shear stress or tensile stress.") .. i think the phrase is beautifully apt ..

Comment: @MoziburUllah, You can't even begin to assess Sartre's philosophical works on the basis of his fiction, and especially not on the basis of an unstudied reader's initial apprehension of his fiction.  This is especially true when your comments make it clear that you completely missed the point.

Comment: @Seldom, is the work you are referring to [this one](http://thefictionsofjeanpaulsartre.blogspot.com/2009/07/he-was-my-teacher-gilles-deleuze-on.html)?  If not, where can I read it?  I believe I can answer your question, but I want to ensure that I am interpreting Deleuze correctly.

Comment: @Seldom, Can you also edit your question to explain how you interpret the Deleuze quote in context of Sartre's work?  It would be difficult to determine if the proposed characterization is fair without understanding the resultant characterization that you are interpreting from the metaphors.

Comment: ? .. the point was to ask if Deleuze's interpretation fair, not is my interpretation of his interpretation fair. Also yes, That seems to be the right article.

Comment: This could maybe use a bit more context -- I think quoting even a tiny bit more of *He was my Teacher* would do a lot to improve the likelihood of a good answer